# Vyper mapping inside a struct

Tags: mapping, struct, vyper

Is it possible to have a mapping inside a struct for vyper? For example:

```py
struct Teddy:
    id: uint256
    year: uint256
    component: map(uint256, uint256)

teddies: private(map(uint256, Teddy))
```

So for the above, component takes a component number as a key and returns the id of the component (e.g. component[0] = 1234, component[1] = 2438...).
If this is possible, how do you instantiate an instance if you do not not need to do anything initially for component. Would it be just:

```
def __init__():
    teddies[0].id = 0
    teddies[0].year = 2019
```

Comment: Did you try it? If so, did it work as expected? If not, what went wrong? Did you see an error message? Or did the contract not behave as you intended?

Comment: I tried compiling my code but it does not compile. When I took out the body of init function it still does not compile in the remix compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below code compiles at [vyper.online](https://vyper.online/). I had to drop the `private` and add `self.` to your accesses of the state variable `teddies`:

```py
struct Teddy:
    id: uint256
    year: uint256
    component: map(uint256, uint256)

teddies: map(uint256, Teddy)

@public
def __init__():
    self.teddies[0].id = 0
    self.teddies[0].year = 2019
```